# drying up rails controller code for data export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not sure if this is an appropriate question so forgive me.

I have the following code in a controller action

```
unless @users.empty?
  book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
  sheet1 = book.create_worksheet :name => 'export'
  sheet1.row(0).concat ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"]
  @users.each_with_index do |e, i|
    sheet1.row(i+1).concat([e.field1, e.field2, e.field3])
  end
  require 'stringio'
  data = StringIO.new ''
  book.write data
  send_data data.string, :type=>"application/excel", :disposition=>'attachment', :filename => "export_#{l(Date.today)}.xls"
end
```

This allows me to have a button on a form that runs an export. Whilst this is very useful, I am using this code all over the place. In fact, I have 19 instances of this code across various controllers in the app. Is there a way I can move this code to another file, and pass into it a hash of the labels and fields so that I only have to maintain one instance of the export code?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basic of `MVC` is to have as much as skinnier controllers, and your case is perfect example, to prevent to repeat your code.

Solution for this is to move your code to `models` the `M` in the `MVC` pattern, it is responsible for all the business logic.

Move this method to the `module`.
In `app/models/concers/` folder create new file `sheetable.rb`

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Sheetable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods    
    def new_sheet objects
      unless objects.empty?
        book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
        sheet1 = book.create_worksheet :name => 'export'
        sheet1.row(0).concat ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"]
        objects.each_with_index do |e, i|
          sheet1.row(i+1).concat([e.field1, e.field2, e.field3])
        end
        require 'stringio'
        data = StringIO.new ''
        book.write data    
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now include `module` in your `model` and it will have class `method` `new_sheet`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  include Sheetable
  ...
end
```

or in other model

```
class OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  include Sheetable
  ...
end
```

To use this

```
data = User.new_sheet(@users) # or OtherModel.new_sheet(@other_models)
if data
 send_data data.string, :type=>"application/excel", :disposition=>'attachment', :filename => "export_#{l(Date.today)}.xls"
end
```

Now you have moved the logic to the `model` next step is to refactor this method, make it more simpler.

Comment: yep, the problem is instead of having 19 instances of the code in 19 controllers, I would now have 19 instances of the code in 19 models - not sure that's a massive step forward?

Comment: How do I pass in specific label and field names?

Comment: add more attributes to the `method`, `label`, `names`, ... then change the method correspondingly

Comment: Awesome that should be more than enough to get me going, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd begin with moving the code to where the responsibility belongs. It seems that you're exporting data of a certain set of users to a spreadsheet. So I'd move the code to the User class, e.g.

```
def self.export_subset_to_spreadsheet(users)
  ... your code ...
end
```

and then call it from your controller with `User.export_subset_to_spreadsheet(@users)`.

This is step one. You can certainly take it further from there, but at least this allows you to get rid of the most pressing problem: the 19 duplications of that whole block of code.

Comment: yep, the problem is instead of having 19 instances of the code in 19 controllers, I would now have 19 instances of the code in 19 models - not sure that's a massive step forward?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would have 19 models... what are the varying items items in the 19 instances? (although I see you might already have been helped by @Nermin's answer; as mentioned there, it's as easy as adding the list of labels and field names as extra arguments to the method signature, e.g. `def self.export_to_subset_to_spreadsheet(users, labels, fieldnames)`)